# Load external js from an object, then use the same object's functions after loaded

Tags: javascript, google-maps, object, callback, dom-events

Making a script which must to be one-lined to attach Google Maps everywhere in our site.

Sometimes 10 maps same time, so I was needed a function to build an object which can build maps. The problem is when I'm loading the maps.js even if it does not need it (case count maps = 0).

So I started to make this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ var map = new initmap(0, 'country_tinymap_canvas', {'longitude': {LONG}, 'latitude': {LAT}} ) }, false);
```

this binds on `domready` to load my maps. {LONG} and {LAT} are smarty-alike PHP variables, imagine those are numbers.

Also made a tiny callback handler for the Google Maps API callback.

```
window.___gmapsready = function(){
    console.log("o/ - map here!");
    $(window).trigger('gmapsready');
}
```

when I'm making the new map it constructs an `initmap` object

```
function initmap(type,container,params) {
    var self = this;
    this.container = container;
    this.type = type;
    this.params = params;

    this.makemap = function()
    {
        console.log("doin map.");
        var mapc = document.getElementById(this.container);
        if (mapc != null)
        {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapc, window.___gmaps);
            var marker;

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(this.params.longitude,this.params.latitude),
                image: image,
                draggable: false,
                map: map
            });
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(this.params.longitude,this.params.latitude));
        }
        console.log("map done, unset vars etc.");
    }

    this.checkload = function()
    {
        console.log("houston houston got map?");
        if (typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object')
        {
            console.log("thanks bro.");
            self.makemap();
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("nop. but i'm gonna load it.");
            var s = document.createElement("script");
            s.type = "text/javascript";
            s.src  = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true&callback=___gmapsready";
            $("head").append(s); 
            document.addEventListener("gmapsready", self.makemap);
        }
    }
    this.checkload();
}
```

The problem is that I can't add the function `makemap` to be called by the `gmapsready` event. Could you help me please how to do this?

Everything is fine but the `document.addEventListener("gmapsready", self.makemap);` call.

Aye also tried with `document.addEventListener("gmapsready", function(event){self.makemap(event)}, false);` gave the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix custom jQuery events with native browser `addEventListener`. Try this instead:

`$(window).on('gmapsready',function() { self.makemap();});`

Comment: true, i forgot i don't have jquery at that moment :D so i have to define the event in native js.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you are using jquery or not... but this is jquery `$(window).trigger('gmapsready');`